# How to set URL for image with view method properly?

Tags: 8

[Image formatter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21templates%21image-formatter.html.twig/8.2.x) should accept `image_style` and `url` parameters.
I've got `image_style` working but not `url`.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
  // ...
  $variables['image'] = $node->get('field_image')->get($delta)->view(['settings' => ['image_style' => '195', 'url' => '/test']]);
  kint($variables['image']);
  // ...
}
```

[image]

Why **url** is NULL (instead of **/test**)?

Comment: It's probably expecting an URL object?! Try `'url' => \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUserInput('/test');`.

Comment: Also It doesn't work. Eventally I've assigned manually $variables['image']['#url']  = '/test' and it does work.

Comment: And when you try to set `'#url' => '/test'`, with the `#` hashtag?

Comment: No luck. Still NULL.

Comment: I think the docs are incorrect. If you take a look at the [PHP source  of formatter function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21image.field.inc/function/template_preprocess_image_formatter/8.2.x), the URL parameter is not used anywhere. Maybe the URL parameter is some leftover from D7, that is not suported anymore?

Comment: @Hudri Actually, the [image-formatter.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21templates%21image-formatter.html.twig/8.2.x) template file uses it. A preprocess function doesn't necessarily modify every variable passed to a template file.

Answer (score 0):

`$node->get('field_image')->get($delta)->view(['settings' => ['image_style' => '195', 'url' => '/test']]);` doesn't set `#url` because it doesn't handle the *url* key passed in *settings*.

Given the content of the `$variables['image']` array, you just need to set `$variables['image']['#url']` after you obtain the image render array. Remember that the value of `#url` is expected to be a  `\Drupal\Core\Url` object.

```php
// Add the following line at the beginning of the file.
use  Drupal\Core\Url;

function mymodule_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
  // ...
  $variables['image'] = $node->get('field_image')->get($delta)->view(['settings' => ['image_style' => '195']]);
  $variables['image']['#url'] = Url::fromUserInput('/test');
}
```

Given the code used by [`ImageFormatter::viewElements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldFormatter%21ImageFormatter.php/function/ImageFormatter%3A%3AviewElements/8.2.x), and the comment before the code, I would "investigate" to understand if setting the cache context is necessary to avoid cache issues in some cases.

```php
// @todo Wrap in file_url_transform_relative(). This is currently
// impossible. As a work-around, we currently add the 'url.site' cache
// context to ensure different file URLs are generated for different
// sites in a multisite setup, including HTTP and HTTPS versions of the
// same site. Fix in https://www.drupal.org/node/2646744.
      $url = Url::fromUri(file_create_url($image_uri));
      $cache_contexts[] = 'url.site';
```

The comment describes it as work-around to use `file_url_transform_relative()`, but invalidating the cache for different sites in a multisite setup or for HTTP and HTTPS versions of the same site, could be still something that needs to be done.